# Error 500 on Post new entity with TableController and AzureMobileApps

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-mobile-services

I'm experiencing a problem using TableController on AzureMobileApps. I've created a new Azure Mobile App TableController in visual studio using scaffolding. In post I modified the resulting code adding an attach on the dbContext to avoid creating referenced item during insert on the child table. That's the resulting code:

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostLocation(Location item)
    {
        _context.Accounts.Attach(item.LocationAccount);
        _context.Categories.Attach(item.PrimaryCategory);

        Location current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }
```

The problem is that each time I invoke the post method I get a 500 internal server error on the "CreatedAtRoute" event even if the entity has been correctly inserted.

Any idea on what is the problem ?!

UPDATE: Entity Model

```
public class Account : EntityData
{
    public Account()
    {
        this.Locations = new HashSet<Location>();
    }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; private set; }
}

public class Location : EntityData
{
    [Required]
    public Account LocationAccount { get; set; }

    ........
}
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, before you adding `Attach` related code, if the `LocationAccount`,`PrimaryCategory` are the new items, then they would be created automatically. If any of them (`LocationAccount`,`PrimaryCategory`) exists in the database table, then you would retrieve the 409 status code.

Based on my test, after added `Attach` related code, if `LocationAccount` and `PrimaryCategory` exist, then you could create new `Location` item successfully. But if any of them does not exist, then you may get the error as follows:

[image]

Per my understanding, you need to check if the navigation properties of `Location` exist. For the existing navigation property item you could use the `DbSet.Attach` method to stop the attached entity from inserting, while the new navigation property item, you need to use `DbSet.Add` or do nothing.

Moreover, you could add the following code in the `ConfigureMobileApp` method of your `Startup.MobileApp.cs` file for including error details and return to your client side.

```
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

**UPDATE:**

By default, the referenced Entities (`LocationAccount`,`PrimaryCategory`) would be inserted, if any entity exists, then you would receive the 409 as follows:

[image]

After added `_context.Accounts.Attach(item.LocationAccount);`, you could create the `Location` entity which has relationships with the existing referenced Entities (`LocationAccount`,`PrimaryCategory`), if the referenced Entities (`LocationAccount`,`PrimaryCategory`) do not exist, you would receive the following error:

[image]

For your scenario, you post the existing referenced Entities (`LocationAccount`,`PrimaryCategory`) for location. Even though the location item could be successfully created, based on your entity models, you may encounter the 500 error as follows:

[image]

You may mark the `Locations` property in `Account` entity model as `JsonIgnore`. Or you need to modify your entity model to ignore the reference Loops when handling serialization.

Moreover, you could leverage the following code snippet instead of `CreatedAtRoute`.

```
return Json(current, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});
```

I also tried to set the global setting for SerializerSettings under `Startup.MobileApp.cs` as follows, but it does not work as expected.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Re‌​ferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Additionally, you could follow [Loop Reference handling in Web API](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Loop-Reference-handling-in-caaffaf7) for more detailed approaches.

Comment: Hi Bruce, thank you for replying me. I've added the attach statement due to default behaviour of TableController, inserting referenced Entity by default. Attaching entity to database context solved this problem (because EF can verify them). Entity are inserted regularly, no exception is thrown if i debug the metod but on the client I receive an Internal Server Error. That lead me to believe that the problem is releated to CreatedAtRout when a many-to-many relationship is defined.....

Comment: I did some additional test for this issue, you could follow the updated part in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, that saved my day.