# Azure App Service Transaction

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I would like to know, if azure app service provides any transaction, so that i could roll back if any thing fails on insertion or updation.

Below is the scenario in which i need transaction support.

I am using Azure App service in .net. The mobile client is calling the Azure app service. I have a requirement in which one table primary key is referenced as a foreign key to another table..So if the referenced foreign key table fails on insertion, i do have to roll back the insertion from the first table.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a requirement in which one table primary key is referenced as a foreign key to another table..So if the referenced foreign key table fails on insertion, i do have to roll back the insertion from the first table.

AFAIK, the referenced entity would be inserted by default. If you create a new TableA record along with the new referenced TableB record against the Table A endpoint, then there has the transaction. Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891640/error-500-on-post-new-entity-with-tablecontroller-and-azuremobileapps/48902146#48902146), you could refer to it.

When you insert a new record to TableB, then send another request to add new record to TableA with the foreign key (TableB's primary key), at this time, there is no transaction. If the insertion for TableA fails, then you need to send a request to delete the previous inserted TableB record manually.

Moreover, I would recommend you follow adrian hall's book about [Relationships](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/relationships/).